# webpackMissingModule application.js on rails with angular app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am following the steps like given by the author. 
Following is the

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "shine",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "stats-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.3",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7"
  }
}
```

I am trying to change the default font to a different font by requiring the bootstrap.

My **application.js** looks like this

```
require("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css");
console.log("Hello world!");
```

And then I restarted the server. I see the text content are in same font-family as before nothing has changed when it should be actually a different font. And the console is giving the error as follows.

**console**

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    at webpackMissingModule
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
// Example webpack configuration with asset fingerprinting in production.
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var StatsPlugin = require('stats-webpack-plugin');

// must match config.webpack.dev_server.port
var devServerPort = 3808;

// set NODE_ENV=production on the environment to add asset fingerprints
var production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

var config = {
  entry: {
    // Sources are expected to live in $app_root/webpack
    'application': './webpack/application.js'
  },

  output: {
    // Build assets directly in to public/webpack/, let webpack know
    // that all webpacked assets start with webpack/

    // must match config.webpack.output_dir
    path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'webpack'),
    publicPath: '/webpack/',

    filename: production ? '[name]-[chunkhash].js' : '[name].js'
  },

  resolve: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'webpack')
  },

  plugins: [
    // must match config.webpack.manifest_filename
    new StatsPlugin('manifest.json', {
      // We only need assetsByChunkName
      chunkModules: false,
      source: false,
      chunks: false,
      modules: false,
      assets: true
    })]
};

if (production) {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: { warnings: false },
      sourceMap: false
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production') }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin()
  );
} else {
  config.devServer = {
    port: devServerPort,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
  };
  config.output.publicPath = '//localhost:' + devServerPort + '/webpack/';
  // Source maps
  config.devtool = 'cheap-module-eval-source-map';
}

module.exports = config;
```

I am not able to figure out if this is npm installing issue or something else. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your using older version of webpack, which I infer after seeing the resolve.root property. From webpack 1 [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root)

> The directory (absolute path) that contains your modules. May also be an array of directories. This setting should be used to add individual directories to the search path.

So when your bootstrap.css files is being resolved instead of searching node_modules, it searches in your

> resolve: { root: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'webpack')}

Comment: Is it ok if I run `npx npmc install` isntead of `npm install` ? Coz at this moment my nodejs version is not compatible with the npm version which was bundled with it.

Comment: Ok I just deleted the **node_modules** folder. Again I installed and created node_modules. Inside node_modules folder there is a bootstrap, then dist, and a css folder and in the end a bootstrap.css file. I restarted the server. Still the same error.

Comment: Please share your webpack.config.js file too, might be there is an issue the config is resolving modules.

Comment: I updated my question with webpack.config.js. Please check.

Comment: 0.9.11. the latest

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the latest, updating my answer above

Comment: "webpack": "^1.14.0", and webpack-rails gem is 0.911